# Method equivalent `onReceive` in iOS 17 with Observable

Tags: swiftui, ios17

With iOS Version 16 and older.
In some cases, we can use Combine and listener object change in `ObservableObject` or `StateObject` by `onReceive`.
Example: Listener on Root View, In-app inactive ... etc. (In some case `onChange` could be not working)

So when migrating the project to iOS 17+, what method is equivalent `onReceive` in iOS 17 with Observable?

`@Bindable` in this case could be not the same.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var vm = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                vm.number += 1
            }, label: {
                Text("\(vm.number)")
            })
        }
        /// What method equivalent `onReceive` in this case
        .onReceive(vm.$number) { _ in
            print("onReceive: \(vm.number)")
        }
    }
}

@Observable
final class ContentViewModel {
    var number = 0
}
```

Comment: can you show some minimum code (even if it does not work) to explain what you are trying to do. You can use similar code of Giau Huynh with `@Observable`. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: I updated. Thank you @work

Comment: Are you looking for `onChange`? Also, don't force yourself to use `@Observable` - `ObservableObject` is not deprecated.

Comment: see this article: https://nilcoalescing.com/blog/ObservationFrameworkOutsideOfSwiftUI/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this approach:

```
import SwiftUI
import Observation
import Combine

@Observable class ContentViewModel {
    var number = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var vm = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("\(vm.number)") {
                vm.number += 1
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
        .onReceive(vm.number.words.publisher) { _ in
            print("---> words onReceive: \(vm.number)")
        }
        // or
        .onReceive(Just(vm.number)) { _ in
            print("---> Just onReceive: \(vm.number)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `vm.number.words`, a typo?

Comment: no typo. The autocomplete presented this, and I tried it because it had a publisher available.
 The docs [Int](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/words-swift.property) says, "A collection containing the words of this value’s binary representation, in order from the least significant to most significant."

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make sense because:

1. in SwiftUI the `View` struct is the view model already you don't need an object, you'll end up trying to re-implement the `View` struct's features which is a waste of time. Instead make lots of custom `View` structs, define only the properties needed in `body` and use `let` for readonly and `@State`/`@Binding` for read/write, group related vars and testable logic in an `@State` struct.
2. `onReceive` is for subscribing to a Combine publisher not for the new `Observable`.
3. `Observable` is for a model class not for view data. You might want that instead of model structs when the model involves relationships.

In SwiftUI you just need model structs (or new model `Observable`s) and `View` data structs (aka view models). Every time you generate a new hierarchy of `View` data structs, SwiftUI diffs it and uses the result to automatically generate the UI layer (i.e. UIKit UIViews) for you, the result of the diff actually is used to init/update/deinit UIView objects that we used to have to do manually with view controllers. Hopefully that helps you understand the `View` struct hierarchy is a view model already.

Comment: This is a design pattern that can be followed but it's not necessary to be the only pattern to follow and others are wrong, attaching a View to a view-model or a controller class is very common in SwiftUI, many of Apple SwiftUI-based project samples use this pattern.